# Create partial refresh page using ASP.net, C# and ajax

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I'm going to create a dynamic template page with ASP.NET using C#.

The template page is consist of three separate frame.
First frame is main menu which is located at the top bar, second frame is sub-menu which is located at the left side bar, and third frame is right side of the side bar which is show the details of the sub-menu .

The process is: If you click on any of the main menu items, the left side bar should refresh only not all the page and show all the sub-menus.

Then once you choose any of the sub-menu, the right side should only refresh and show the details of the sub-menu.

The main point is I don't want to refresh all page by each menu selection.
Could you please guide me for this template?

Appreciate your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try Updatepanel ? or you can use .ajax in jquery to update where you want.

Check out this [UpdatePanel Tips and Tricks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx)

Comment: Dear Maxisam, thanks for the answer. i'm trying the Updatepanel but i have no idea about the jquery. if you dont mind please guide me step by step how to have one sample page with 3 separate part, once the user click on top menu the data send to the second part which is left sub-menu and refresh this part only. then once the user click on left sub-menu send the data to the middle part and refresh the middle part of the page only. or if you have any sample page please send me to get the clear picture of how the passing data between these three part should work at one page. really appreciate.

Comment: Here is a great example if you want to use jQuery to update your page. http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/11/07/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods-by-example.aspx

Comment: appreciate for your reply. but i couldn't run it because it shows error that "BookRepository dose not exist". how should i get ride of this error? thanks

Answer (score 0):

updatepanel will not refresh the whole page but will do full postback .

I suggest to use this: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/40/ASP.NET-and-Ajax-using-XmlHttpRequest

it is better for performance

or
 webserive(asmx), json and jquery:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery

Comment: Dear Bart, thanks for the answer. i have no idea about the json and jquery. if you don't min please guide me step by step how to have one sample page with 3 separate part, once the user click on the top menu the data send to the second part which is left sub-menu and refresh this part only. then once the user click on left sub-menu send the data to the middle part and refresh the middle part of the page only. or if you have any sample page please send me to get the clear picture of how the passing data between these three part should work at one page. really appreciate.